# execute code on first call to the dll

Tags: c#, class-library

I a c# class library. Is there anyway that a method can be run on first call and only on the first call to the dll? ie. similar to in a web application - global.asax - Application_Start method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a static initializer on your interface object. However, you should only expose this Interface class through your DLL that way, and make all other functional calls internal.

```
public class DllInterface
{
    static DllInterface()
    {
        // Do initialization magic here
    }

    // Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: What is interface object? Do you mean a static constructor? It'll run when the class is first loaded, but the op wanted code to run when the *dll* is first called

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I don't know if in c# you can do that, but I don't think so. What you can do is to create a static constructor that it will be called before any other call in a class:

```
public class Foo
{
   static Foo()
   { 
      Console.WriteLine("called first time only");
   }

   public Foo()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("called every new object"); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I searched a while for it and found [this site](http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/12/16/module-initializers-in-csharp/). It looks very promising, but i hadn't the time to test it by myself.

(Currently the site is down for maintenance. Here is the site from [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:q8SS0ZwN1ZYJ:tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/12/16/module-initializers-in-csharp/+http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/12/16/module-initializers-in-csharp/&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&client=opera).)